# How to access text inside an Entry widget from a function in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python GUI assignment in which I have to create a GUI application which will evaluate a single variable function within a specified range of input values. We have to use classes. I have written the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import tkinter.font as font

class eval_interface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Function Evaluator")
        self.topframe = Frame(self.root)
        self.createTopFrame()
        self.topframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.root)
        self.createFrame2()
        self.frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 15, columnspan = 10, sticky = N + S + W + E)
        self.frame3 = Frame(self.root)
        self.createFrame3()
        self.frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=15, columnspan=10, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        self.frame4 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame5 = Frame(self.root)
        self.createFrame5()
        self.frame5.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=15, columnspan=10, sticky=N + S + E + W)
        self.createFrame4()
        self.frame4.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 15, columnspan = 10, sticky = N+S+E+W)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def createTopFrame(self):  #Frame containing title
        title = Label(self.topframe, text="Function evaluator and plotter".center(228, " "), font=font.Font(size=17))
        title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7)

    def createFrame2(self):  #Frame containing function Entry widget
        title = Label(self.frame2, text = "Enter the function in x : ", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N + S + W + E)
        function_entry = Entry(self.frame2, width  = 150)
        function_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N + S + W + E)

    def createFrame3(self):  #Frame containing range Entry widgets
        range_label = Label(self.frame3, text="Enter the range of the function from : ", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        lower_range_entry = Entry(self.frame3, width=10)
        range_label2 = Label(self.frame3, text=" to ")
        upper_range_entry = Entry(self.frame3, width=10)
        range_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        lower_range_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        range_label2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        upper_range_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="nsew")

    def createFrame4(self):  #Frame containing button widgets
        btn_evaluate = Button(self.frame4, text = "Evaluate", font = font.Font(size = 14), command = self.evaluate())
        btn_plot = Button(self.frame4, text = "Plot", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        btn_clear = Button(self.frame4, text = "Clear", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        btn_exit = Button(self.frame4, text = "Exit", font = font.Font(size = 14), command = exit)
        btn_evaluate.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        btn_plot.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        btn_clear.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        btn_exit.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5)

    def createFrame5(self):  #Frame containing Result Textbox
        res_text = Text(self.frame5, width = 95, height = 55, padx = 10)
        res_text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def evaluate(self):
        x = 10

    def clear(self):
        z=12


eval_interface()
```

My question is, how do I access the data inputted by the user in the three entry widgets (in frames 2 and 3) when the Evaluate button is clicked? And after I have accessed the data and done the necessary operations on it, how do I display the result in the Textbox in Frame 5? (I have just coded some random statement in evaluate and clear functions for now to see the output GUI.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `Entry` widgets inside `evaluate()` function, you need to change the three local variables `function_entry`, `lower_range_entry` and `upper_range_entry` to instance variables `self.function_entry`, `self.lower_range_entry` and `self.upper_range_entry`.  Same for the `Text` widget `res_text`.  Then you can get the values from the three `Entry` widgets and insert the result into `self.res_text` inside `evaluate()` function:

```py
    def createFrame2(self):  #Frame containing function Entry widget
        title = Label(self.frame2, text = "Enter the function in x : ", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N + S + W + E)
        self.function_entry = Entry(self.frame2, width  = 150)
        self.function_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N + S + W + E)

    def createFrame3(self):  #Frame containing range Entry widgets
        range_label = Label(self.frame3, text="Enter the range of the function from : ", font = font.Font(size = 14))
        self.lower_range_entry = Entry(self.frame3, width=10)
        range_label2 = Label(self.frame3, text=" to ")
        self.upper_range_entry = Entry(self.frame3, width=10)

        range_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.lower_range_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        range_label2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.upper_range_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="nsew")

    ...

    def createFrame5(self):  #Frame containing Result Textbox
        self.res_text = Text(self.frame5, width = 95, height = 55, padx = 10)
        self.res_text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def evaluate(self):
        # get content from entries
        x = self.function_entry.get()
        lower = self.lower_range_entry.get()
        upper = self.upper_range_entry.get()
        # example on inserting result into text box
        result = ", ".join([x, lower, upper]) # or whatever you want
        self.res_text.insert("end", result)

    ...
```

Also `command=self.evaluate()` inside `createFrame4()` should be `command=self.evaluate` instead.